# keep contents of nofile buffer

Tags: job-control

My plugin creates new buffer, sets buffer type to `nofile` and fills it with text via `job_start` with `out_io`=`buffer`. Simplified code:

```
enew
setl bt=nofile
...
call job_start(cmd, {'out_io': 'buffer', 'out_buf': bufnr('%')})
```

Works fine, but when I switch to new buffer, and then return back, created buffer is empty. So, looks like vim doesn't keep contents of nofile buffers.
Is there any way to keep nofile buffer contents for vim session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `setl bufhidden=hide` to prevent the buffer from getting unloaded when you switch to another buffer.

See also `:help special-buffers`, in particular the entry for "scratch" buffers.

Comment: Excellent! That's what I needed, thank you!